# Запрос на выбор записей из базы данных в указанном диапазоне дат

Tags: php, mysqli

Не работает запрос, помогите разобраться.

```
$t="SELECT * FROM ms_order_trackid mot
LEFT OUTER JOIN ms_order_trackid_note motn
ON motn.order_id = mot.order_id
WHERE mot.date_shipping BETWEEN DATE('%s') AND DATE('%s')  
ORDER BY mot.date_shipping DESC";

$query = sprintf($t, mysqli_real_escape_string($this->sql->dbh, $start), 
mysqli_real_escape_string($this->sql->dbh, $end));
```

Есть 2 таблицы, соединил через `JOIN`. Нужно получить записи в требуемый диапазон дат. Проверял через phpmyadmin и другой sql редактор, запрос работает, возвращает нужный результат. А как ставлю в коде php, не работает. Пробовал `DATE_FORMAT`, `STR_TO_DATE`, результат тот же, либо пусто, либо выводит не те даты. Перечитал и перепробовал разные варианты с форумов, не срабатывает. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: простите, но что вы хотели сделать последними двумя строчками кода?..

Comment: Согласен, лишнее вышло. 
Хотел показать, что делается через mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

1. Первое что делаете - проверяете, что у Вас действительно `$start` и `$end` содержат именнно то, что нужно.
2. Сломайте нос тому, кто посоветовал Вам таким образом подставлять переменные. Это делается примерно вот так:

   ```
   $t = 'SELECT * FROM `ms_order_trackid` `mot`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `ms_order_trackid_note` `motn`
       ON `motn`.`order_id` = `mot`.`order_id`
       WHERE `mot`.`date_shipping` BETWEEN DATE(?) AND DATE(?)  
       ORDER BY `mot`.`date_shipping` DESC';
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bind_param('ss', $start, $end);
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       // делаете что нужно
   }
   ```

P.S. зря вообще сделали функцию mysqli_real_escape_string. Только толкает людей на жуткие вещи.

Comment: 1. $start и $end содержат дату в строковом виде (2017-10-01 и 2017-10-20). В таблице дата хранится в формате data
2. Согласен, Ваше решение более приемлемо, но результата все равно нет. 
Если уберу из запроса join и оставлю одну таблицу, код работает. Так же есть подозрение, что при передаче строкового типа для сравнения с датой тоже может быть проблемным местом, но не знаю как это правильно сделать.

Comment: @Виктор, извиняюсь, немного переделал. Вот так попробуйте. На счёт того что Вы передаёте строки, а не дату можете не волноваться - тут всё норм должно быть.

Comment: Сработал :) Спасибо! Если можно, в двух словах, в чем же все таки ступор был? Просидел, не смог разобраться.

Comment: @Виктор, не знаю. Вы же не показали как Вы именно запрос делаете и выбираете данные)

Comment: Тот "ужастик" передается сюда
public function selectDefaultListTrackID($query) {
  $result = mysqli_query($this->dbh, $query);

  if(!$result)
   die(mysqli_error($this->dbh));

  $arr = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $arr[] = $row;
  }

  return $arr;
 }

Comment: @Виктор, не знаю. Иногда лучше и не знать, почему некоторые вещи не работали. Я вообще не рекомендовал бы Вам использовать методы mysqli_query и mysqli_real_escape_string. Крайне редки ситуации, в которых может понадобиться второй метод. Первый метод стоит использовать лишь для неизменных запросов.